# Android geocoding works consistently for certain zip codes and fails consistently for others. All valid zipcodes

Tags: java, android, geocoding

When using Android Geocoding using zip codes I consistently get empty address values for certain zip codes (ex. 13662, 22427, and 22405) but I get usable correct values for other zip codes (ex. 02835, 13667, 10001). All 6 of these are valid US zip codes but 3 consistently work, 3 consistently fail. Any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Android Geocoder is not very reliable, it may not return any values for certain addresses. You can use the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) entirely, which requires you to make an HTTP request. Or you can set up a check to request the address from Google only if the Geocoder returns null.